# Android - webview postURL doesn't send data

Tags: android, webview, postdata

I'm trying to send data as post, with webview but it doesn't work, 
follow my code below.....

```
        WebView webview = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(webview);
        byte[] post = EncodingUtils.getBytes("SOMEDATA","UTF-8");
        webview.postUrl("http://posttestserver.com/post.php", post);
```

**site result is :**

**Successfully dumped 0 post variables. View it at 
http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2014/07/24/07.59.4218588627 Post body was 0 chars long.**

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this code and it worked properly:

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
byte[] post = EncodingUtils.getBytes("ticket=1234567","BASE64");
webview.postUrl("http://posttestserver.com/post.php", post);
```

In your comment you said `body was 0 chars long`, yes, but the params are received properly.

Note utf-8 as the charset didn't work for me.

Comment: EncodingUtils has been removed from Android P. What is the alternative can be used for the same.

Answer (score -1):

*Try posting valid data in post params for url -*

For example -

```
String url = "http://posttestserver.com/post.php";
String postData = "username=my_username&password=my_password";
webview.postUrl(url,EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "UTF-8"));
```

See - [webview-posturl-postdata](http://glorious-arvind.blogspot.in/2012/11/webview-posturl-postdata.html).

Comment: i try      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  WebView webview = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
  setContentView(webview);
  String postData = "ticket=123456";
  webview.postUrl("http://posttestserver.com/post.php",EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
same problem....  webview opens with Post body was 0 chars long.

Comment: EncodingUtils has been removed from Android P. What is the alternative can be used for the same.